# Beaglebone Black: changing the location of the mass storage folder

Tags: linux, beagleboneblack

By default, on the version of Debian we're using, the Beaglebone black mounts /boot/uboot as the folder that is presented as mass storage (so I see this folder's contents when I connect it to my PC). I would like to change the folder to a publically readable and writeable directory at boot time, but am struggling to find the startup script where the mount actually takes place. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look to this question:
[Where is g_multi configured in BeagleBone Black?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33016961/where-is-g-multi-configured-in-beaglebone-black/33020999)

As some of the comments stated, it is a bit difficult to make this work.

You would have to share its mounting on a timely basis. If you remove g_multi module (or the mass storage specific module) then the PC sees the device as disconnected, and you load module again it gets reconnected. You could make the changes to the filesystem in the meanwhile. If shared filesystem is a bit large, you could prepare two filesystems, one for writing and the shared one could get synchronized with rsync or something similar.

The schema would be something like this:

writing to the alternate filesystem -> module unloading -> mounting rw -> rsync -> unmounting -> module loading

But you will always have the problem of device getting disconnected and reconnected again in the PC. You could synchronize it someway, but that is a different problem.

Answer (score -1):

All static mounts are done using /etc/fstab

Comment: This is my fstab:

# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
UUID=d8ca0096-a415-4861-8f7e-921343039af5  /  ext4  noatime,errors=remount-ro  0  1
debugfs  /sys/kernel/debug  debugfs  defaults  0  0

Comment: If you're thinking about connecting the board to your PC and transfering files to it using the mass storage protocol, that's a really bad idea. The filesystem is already mounted on the device and you're writing to it behind its back. That's why it is RO.

If you want to transfer files to and from it, use FTP, NFS or SCP.

Comment: The mass storage is for retrieving files written on the BBB by our application. I should, theoretically, be able to move the mount point from /media/BEAGLEBONE to /media/MYAPP without too much pain, no?

Comment: The filesystem can either be RO or RW. If you allow MSC, then it needs to be RO, as long as the other (BBB) os is having the filesystem mounted.

Comment: Isn't it possible to transfer the files using networking? NFS explicitly allows for concurrent RW-access.

Comment: Of course it's POSSIBLE - but I don't think I have the time to invest in that.

Comment: I agree with @Kavli. But I recommend using Filezilla(scp gui application). If you've installed proper usb drivers for BBB on windows, you can browse and access files on BBB at 192.168.7.2 on windows using Filezilla with scp protocol.